# Pass weights into CrossEntropyLoss in correct order

Tags: python, pytorch

I'm trying to use weight in `torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss`,

but I'm not sure which order should I put

e.g.

```
    weight = torch.tensor([1.0, 52337/34649, 52337/11066]).to(device)

    criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss(weight=weight)
```

My class0 has 52337 examples it's labeled as `0` in target value, so I take 1.0

My class1 has 34649 examples it's labeled as `2` in target value, so I take 52337/34649

My class2 has 34649 examples it's labeled as `1` in target value, so I take 52337/11066

but I'm not sure which order should put in `weight` array,

**My question is**

Is there a way to show what is class0, class1 and class2 in CrossEntropy?
or the CrossEntropy will figure out the weights by itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after you define your criterion as above you will have to call it like:

```
loss = criterion (inputs, targets)
```

the targets will be encoded 0 .. C-1 where C is number of classes (0,1 or 2 in your case). So your weights order and number should correspond to your targets.